# Cycle.js: What is the best way to handle File Drag and Drop

Tags: cyclejs

I want my Cycle.js web application to read data from a file dropped by the user on the page. I have something working by I'm not sure it is the right way to do it. Moreover, my component isn't easily testable because it needs a proper DragEvent with files in it which is difficult to cradt outside the browser (maybe with jsdom ?).

Here's what I have so far:

```js
// src/index.ts
// I need the line below somewhere, not sure it's the right place
document.addEventListener("dragover", (dragEvent) => {
  dragEvent.preventDefault();
});
```

Then my FileLoader component will listen to 'drop' events and read file:

```js
function readFile(file: File): Stream<string> {
  return xs.create({
    start: (listener) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = (_progressEvent) => {
        listener.next(reader.result as string);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    },
    stop: () => {
      /* nothing to stop */
    },
  });
}

DOM.select(".dropzone")
  .events("drop", { preventDefault: true })
  .map((dragEvent) => dragEvent.dataTransfer.files[0])
  .map(file => readFile(file))
  .flatten()
}
```

Since the reading of a File is some kind of side-effects, I wonder if I should do it in a driver instead but I'm not sure how to do it. The driver would take a Stream of DragEvent (or a Stream of File) as sink and return a source of file contents ?